# can't open .XIB to another lower system version

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode6, xcode5, xib

In my mac project I have created .XIB file in xcode 5.1.1(OSX 10.10.2). This .XIB file i can't open in xcode 5.1.1(OSX 10.8.5) another system.

**Try below methods:**

- open this file via pull from source control.
- copy and paste this file to another system(OSX 10.8.5).
- Change the 'open in' as xcode 5.1 and 'build for' as 'osx 10.8' in xcode.

But those method not working for me.

Please help me to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to upgrade to Xcode 6 and open the file there. Both Xcode 5 and 6 can be installed on the same system, so if you must use Xcode 5 on your current system, at least you can copy and paste the contents of the file.

Note that you will not be able to submit apps using Xcode 5 anymore as of February 2015.

Comment: i have developing mac project. my system have yosimite and xcode 5 and my friend system have mountain line and xcode 5.  both are using xcode 5 but different osx. So ploblem is osx. So please suggest me for this. thanks jay...!